# Why is Chart.js not attaching a second Chart when adding the container with javascript?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

**Problem:**

I have two Chart.js charts. I want to attach the containers for these charts with javascript.
When I do this, only the second chart gets rendered properly. But the first chart is not displayed. Looking at the chart object, I found that the first chart has `attached: false` whereas the second has `attached: true`, which might be the diagnosis. But I don't understand why this happens.

When I define the same containers in the `index.html`, the problem does not occur. Why is that happening?

Thank you for your help.

Working code: https://codepen.io/docoda/pen/GRdvwqV

**index.html**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**index.js**

```
// First Chart

const labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June']

const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First dataset',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
  }]
}

const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {}
}

// Add Chart-JS Container
const container = document.getElementById("container")
container.innerHTML += '<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>'

// Make Chart
const myChart1 = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
)

// Second Chart

const config2 = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {}
}

// Add Chart-JS Container
container.innerHTML += '<canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>'
const myChart2 = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart2'),
  config2
)

console.log(myChart1, myChart2)
```

---

**Solution**

As LeeLenalee said, `.innerHTML +=` will change the DOM without recreating the first canvas. You can either add the containers before creating the charts, or just use `.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ...)` instead of `.innerHTML +=`.

Comment: `innerHTML += ...` re-creates the already existing child elements. So your `#myChart` canvas element gets _replaced_ by a new one, when you add your second canvas. But for that _new_ first one, the chart initialization never happened. Either add _both_ your canvas elements first using innerHTML, and initialize them afterwards - or use a different method of adding elements, that does not re-create the already existing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dom gets edited so the chart that is rendered is now getting a new canvas without you re making the chart, this can be fixed by first adding the canvases to the dom before creating the charts:

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container")
container.innerHTML += '<canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>'
container.innerHTML += '<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>'

const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {}
}

// Make Chart
const myChart1 = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
)

// Second Chart

const config2 = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {}
}

// Add Chart-JS Container
const myChart2 = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart2'),
  config2
)
```

https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/PoeKxBZ

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new div for each new chart for it to work.

index.html

```
<div id="container"></div>
// Add a new div for the 2nd chart
<div id="container2"></div>
```

index.js

```
// ...

// Declare the var for the 2nd div container
const container2 = document.getElementById("container2")

// Add Chart-JS Container using the 2nd div
container2.innerHTML += '<canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>'
const myChart2 = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart2'),
  config2
)
```

Working codepen here https://codepen.io/SuperNoobi/pen/rNvzQQr

Comment: This is not true, you can add both of them in the same div, you just need  to make sure you add the canvases before creating the charts

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the charts once the DOM is loaded:

```js
...

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // Make Chart
    const myChart1 = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    )

    const myChart2 = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart2'),
      config2
    )
});

...
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/mavyfaby/pen/xxjLQQM